# Android ListView press image on an item

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView with uniqe rows. 
1 Picture and 1 TextView in a row.
I want to press the picture and toast the selected listitem position.
So This picture is works as a button.
My code is work. But its not bad? 
What happen if first the onClick() method run after run the onItemClick() ? Or its never happens?

Thanks!

```
private ListView list;
private int pressedId;
```

...

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        pressedId = position;
                    }
                });
```

...

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.imageView_delete:
            {
                Toast.makeText(this,"id:"+pressedId,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
```

Comment: could you clarify the question? I'm unsure on what the issue is

Comment: in your listviews getView() set your OnClickListener there.

Comment: Thanks Jasz, its a good idea. i do that :)

Comment: And, when i press in the image, how i can call the Activity, to refresh list?

Comment: get your adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class ExampleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ExampleClass> {

    public ServicesChildAdapter(Context context, List<ExampleClass> items) {
        super(context, R.layout.example_layout, items);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ItemHolder holder;
        final ExampleClass CurrentItem = items.get(position);
        if (convertView== null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.example_layout, parent, false);
            holder = new ItemHolder();
            holder.ExampleImageView= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ExampleImageView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ItemHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.CurrentItem = CurrentItem;

            //TODO: Click listener on the view you want.
            holder.RemoveItemTextView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){ 
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.d(getClass.getSimpleName(), "item was clicked");
                }
            });
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```